# Existence of Short Exact Sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

This question is motivated by attempting to find the indecomposable modules over $R=\mathbb{K}[X]/(X^n)$. This can be done using the structure theorem assuming we know that the indecomposable modules are all finitely generated. This in fact is the case (see [Classification of indecomposable modules over a given ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111686/classification-of-indecomposable-modules-over-a-given-ring)). The proof in this post uses the fact that given some indecomposable $R$-module $M$, there exists $m \in M$ such that $X^{i-1}m \neq 0$ where $Ann_R(M)=(X^i)$. It is then proven that $M \cong Rm$.

In looking for an alternative proof, I managed to prove that $R$ is quasi-Frobenius. This follows from the fact that the ideals of $R$ are of the form $([X^i])$ where $0 \leq i \leq n$. Now, given that $R$ is quasi-Frobenius, we know that every projective $R$-module is injective. In particular, $Rm$ is injective (where we have defined $m$ above). So we have reduced our original problem to constructing a short exact sequence of the following form.
$$0 \to Rm \to M \xrightarrow{f} f(M) \to 0 $$

Does such a short exact sequence exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessarily the case that $Rm$ is injective (or projective) as an $R$-module. For example, take $M=R/(X)$.

However, you can make your proof work by considering $M$ as a module for $S=\mathbb{K}[X]/(X^i)$, where $\text{Ann}_R(M)=(X^i)$. If $m\in M$ is an element with $X^{i-1}m\neq0$, then there is a short exact sequence of $S$-modules
$$0\to S\to M\stackrel{f}{\to}f(M)\to0,$$
where the map $S\to M$ is $s\mapsto sm$, and $S$ is quasi-Frobenius and so this sequence splits.